# ASP.NET Application – Tracing

Tags: asp.net, trace

We are working on an ASP.NET application and planned to use tracing.

Here I need few clarifications.

Is it the common practice that people use trace statements in .NET real time applications?   If so could anyone please refer a document with standard way of writing these in real time web applications.

Many Thanks,

Regards.

Bhavna.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at ELMAH?

[Logging Error Details with ELMAH](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/hosting/tutorial-14-cs.aspx)

> Error Logging Modules And Handlers
>   (ELMAH) offers an approach to logging
>   runtime errors in a production
>   environment. ELMAH is a free, open
>   source error logging library that
>   includes features like error filtering
>   and the ability to view the error log
>   from a web page, as an RSS feed, or to
>   download it as a comma-delimited file.

[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a commonly used approach to logging (this is the approach I usually use).

Searching SO is always a good idea:

- [Logging for ASP.NET - Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565471/logging-for-asp-net-best-practices)
- [ASP.NET Logging - log4net or health monitoring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651782/asp-net-logging-log4net-or-health-monitoring)
- [Write to a log file in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284868/write-to-a-log-file-in-asp-net)